# jQuery $().css("content") returning the string "normal" in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm using the CSS `content` attribute to pass some values from my LESS stylesheet to JavaScript (to use some colors defined in LESS in Canvas elements).
To make my life easier I decided to place these values in a easy way to parse them in JavaScript.

LESS code:

```
div#colorChart-critical {
   content:'@{critical-highest},@{critical-veryhigh},@{critical-high},@{critical-low},@{critical-medium},@{critical-verylow}';
}
```

which when compiled brings the following CSS:

```
div#colorChart-critical6 {
    content: '#ff0000,#ff7200,#fffc00,#0000ff,#a200ff,#00ff00';
}
```

Then I try to read them using jQuery:

```
$("div#colorChart-critical").css("content").split(",");
```

The problem is that in IE9 calling `$("div#colorChart-critical").css("content")` is returning the string `"normal"` for some reason. Opera, Firefox, Safari and Chrome works fine.

Why does this happen in IE9?

Any work-around this issue on IE9? If not any other CSS atribute I can put random texts in?

I could use something like:

```
background: url(#ff0000,#ff7200,#fffc00,#0000ff,#a200ff,#00ff00);
```

But this would generate errors on the console.

Comment: Very interesting approach, but I can't help but think that CSS is just not meant for this kind of thing. Anyway you can just take a different approach?

Comment: I don't believe you can reliably read CSS values in that way. The browser is going to parse the stylesheet first, and may remove/modify values at its discretion.  If nothing else, there's no guarantee that some functionality you're relying on won't change in a later update.

Comment: @ZachL Indeed it's not meant to do things like this. I want to do this in this manner because my LESS code generates multiple skins for my website so it's not practical to have the colors set manually in the javascript.

Comment: @SamDufel Indeed it's not reliable, BUT the content CSS atribute is not parsed by the browser. Note the single quotes there, you need those and the string inside the quotes is not parsed by the browser. That is why I am using it.

Comment: @Hoffmann: The declaration *has* to be parsed by the browser before it can determine that it can't actually use it and discard it.

Comment: Well it's more like it gets parsed but remains unchanged when using .getComputedStyle() or $().css(), at least on all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BoltClock answer shows the cause of my problems. I found a work-around by using the font-family instead of the content CSS property.

My LESS code:

```
div#colorChart-maincolors {
    font-family: '@{colorChart1},@{colorChart2},@{colorChart3},@{colorChart4},@{colorChart5},@{colorChart6}';
}
```

Which compiled into CSS gives:

```
div#colorChart-maincolors {
  font-family: '#c0392b,#2980b9,#2ecc71,#f1c40f,#ecf0f1,#34495e';
}
```

The string can be acquired using:

```
removeQuotes= function(string) {
   return string.replace(/^['"]+|\s+|\\|(;\s?})+|['"]$/g, '');
};
removeQuotes($("#colorChart-maincolors").css("font-family")); //add a .split(',') to get the colors as an array
```

The function removeQuotes is necessary because each browser adds a different kind of quotes into the return of getComputedStyle (and by extension the jQuery .css() method). IE9 adds a double quote, Webkit adds a single quote.

See this post on CSS tricks: http://css-tricks.com/making-sass-talk-to-javascript-with-json/ for more information.

Comment: Using font-family instead of content was a great idea, works like a charm, thanks :)

Comment: @IstvánUjj-Mészáros it is an awful hack, I wish there was a way to get these values without changing my build lifecycle too much,  LESS should have provided some keyword to export these variables into a JSON file or something.

Comment: Agree, but the hack works fine :) Just fixed my bootstrap customizer for IE. http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/

Comment: I am also using this hack, now. I tested it on various browsers and this seems to be a good solution to increase the browser compatibility.

Comment: @klopfdreh for browser compatibility yes, for sanity not so much

Answer (score 7):

It's because `content` as defined in CSS2.1 doesn't work on elements, only on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. IE9 is simply following the CSS2.1 spec here, which [mandates](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) that `content` on elements be computed to `normal`, always.

I don't know why other browsers would return the value you have defined, especially considering that [`.css()` makes use of `getComputedStyle()` on those browsers](http://api.jquery.com/css). If they're implementing CSS2.1 `content`, then they're violating CSS2.1 by not computing the value to `normal`. If they're preparing for a late CSS3 implementation, whatever that may be, then it would make sense that they implement it on actual elements somehow... shame on them either way.

Which brings me to another point: if you're not actually trying to use CSS to modify the content of an element, don't use `content`, even if the fact that it's not defined for use with elements is the reason you're making use of this technique in the first place. You can try assigning those colors to certain classes, creating a hidden element and querying that element's color styles instead.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed response. I forgot to mention that my div#colorChart-critical is already hidden, I was just using content because it was easier to set and get all the colors at once. I would like to avoid creating an element for each color. Since I have multiple skins for my page and I would like to avoid forcing each skin to always have X colors (the way it works now each skin can have any number of colors). My chart library ( flotcharts.org ) just rotates to the first color if there are not enough in the array of colors provided to it to render all the series in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace(/["']/g, "")` to remove extra quotation from string

`""string""` will be change to `"string"`